# CBPeripheral, Get Local Peripheral Identifier

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ibeacon, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

I faced a problem about CoreBluetooth Framework.

As Example, I have two devices and each device performs both advertising and scanning. So, I use `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralManager` on each.

So, to simplify problem, let's assume that **Device1** is broadcasting and **Device2** scanning.

When `CBCentralManager` on **Device2** discover the **Device1**, callback 
`centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:`
is called and I can get **Device1** identifier by calling `[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]`.

How then I can get my local device (**Device2**) Identifier? 
I mean in case that both devices are advertising, **Device1** will discover **Device2** too and get it's peripheral identifier, but
How can I get exact this identifier (some kind of self-address) on **Device2**?

P.S. I know that this Identifier is not unique for each device and can change over the time, it's not a problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this case, I need an Identify Device 1 and when device 2 scan I know it was device 1

Comment: @Bassem I'm in the same situation, and the way I'm handling it is thus: Each peripheral always sends at least one common type of object. It includes a UUID generated by the peripheral. When the central receives it, it can then associate that peripheral-generated UUID with the ID of the peripheral. Then, for example, if the devices disconnect, when a notification comes that the services are invalid, those items can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this.  The identifier returned by `[peripheral.identifier UUIDString]` is auto generated by iOS on the receiving device.  It is seeded by the transmitter Mac address (which does not change) and the time the device starts being seen by iOS (which does change).

Because of the second factor is not predictable  and the fact that the id generation algorithm is not published, you cannot predict what this id will be on the transmitter side.

Bottom line, if you want a predictable unique id, you cannot use this field

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to send this value from receiving device somehow? @davidgyoung

Comment: You could have an identifier as a GATT characteristic, but you would need to establish a BLE connection to read it.  That is a little slow and error prone, but possible.

Comment: Thanks, @davidgyoung. But can I connect to peripheral in Background? Can I accept this connection too or it requires foreground state?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. "... if your app has not specified the bluetooth-peripheral background mode, the contents of its services become disabled when it is in the background or in a suspended state; any remote central trying to access the service’s characteristic value or characteristic descriptors receives an error." -- https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/index.html

Comment: Thanks, @davidgyoung. But what if I specify it, will I able to connect devices in bg then? Because I've tried but with no result(

Comment: @davidgyoung Can you tell me if that identifier can change over the time? Can I use this identifier to reconnect my peripheral?

Comment: The identifier can change over time, yes, although in my experience it is stable on a per session basis.  The implementation undocumented, but it may be stable until you reboot the phone.  I do not believe there are any APIs to connect based on this identifier alone.